# Can useLoaderData be used in the sibling components of the component in which loader() is used in ReactRouter v6.9.0. If yes then how?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have fetched data using loader in my `MoviePage` component and I am using this data by using `useLoaderData`. Now I want to use this data in sibling components like `MoviePage/Genre1`, `MoviePage/Genre2` etc.
For this I am trying to use `useLoaderData` in the sibling components, but the result is being read as 'undefined'. Does this mean that `useLoaderData` can be used only in the route component in which loader has been used. If yes, then how can I use the result returned in the other `Genre` components?

This is how my routes are defined.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />, // Wrapper Component
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <HomePage />,
      },
      {
        path: "movies",
        element: <Root2 />,
        children: [
          {
            index: true,
            element: <MoviePage />,
            loader: async () => {
              const options = {
                method: "GET",
                url: "https://ott-details.p.rapidapi.com/advancedsearch",
                params: {
                  start_year: "1970",
                  end_year: "2020",
                  min_imdb: "6",
                  max_imdb: "10",
                  genre: "action",
                  language: "english",
                  type: "movie",
                  sort: "latest",
                  page: "1",
                },
                headers: {
                  "X-RapidAPI-Key": "{api-key}",
                  "X-RapidAPI-Host": "ott-details.p.rapidapi.com",
                },
              };

              const response = await axios.request(options);
              if (!response.ok) {
                return response.data;
              } else {
                console.log(response.status);
              }
            },
          },
          { path: "Genre1", element: <Genre1 /> },
          { path: "Genre2", element: <Genre2 /> },
          { path: "Genre3", element: <Genre3 /> },
          { path: ":genre/:movieId", element: <MovieDetail /> },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking to use the [`useRouteLoaderData`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-route-loader-data) hook instead of the [`useLoaderData`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-loader-data) hook.

> `useRouteLoaderData`
>
> This hook makes the data at any currently rendered route available
> anywhere in the tree. This is useful for components deep in the tree
> needing data from routes much farther up, as well as parent routes
> needing the data of child routes deeper in the tree.
>
> > Important: This feature only works if using a data router, see
> > [Picking a Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router)

You may only need to provide an `id` prop for the route. You may need to promote the loader function to the parent layout route of the `MoviePage` and genre routes/components. This is so the data remains available when the nested routes change.

```js
const movieLoader  = async () => {
  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://ott-details.p.rapidapi.com/advancedsearch",
    params: {
      start_year: "1970",
      end_year: "2020",
      min_imdb: "6",
      max_imdb: "10",
      genre: "action",
      language: "english",
      type: "movie",
      sort: "latest",
      page: "1",
    },
    headers: {
      "X-RapidAPI-Key": "{api-key}",
      "X-RapidAPI-Host": "ott-details.p.rapidapi.com",
    },
  };

  const response = await axios.request(options);
  if (!response.ok) {
    return response.data;
  } else {
    console.log(response.status);
  }
},
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <HomePage /> },
      {
        id: "movies", // <-- add route id
        path: "movies",
        element: <Root2 />,
        loader: movieLoader, // <-- promote loader
        children: [
          { index: true, element: <MoviePage /> },
          { path: "Genre1", element: <Genre1 /> },
          { path: "Genre2", element: <Genre2 /> },
          { path: "Genre3", element: <Genre3 /> },
          { path: ":genre/:movieId", element: <MovieDetail /> },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

In any of the genre components, use the `useRouteLoaderData` hook and provide the appropriate route id.

```js
const movieData = useRouteLoaderData("movies");
```